# Flask-Mail to receive user emails?

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

I'm currently building a website / application in Python using Flask. 
I've been following a few tutorials online about contact forms and such using Flask-Mail, Flask-wtforms.

My issue is that the implementations of Flask-Mail I've come across seem to be primarily aimed at sending users emails as opposed to allowing users to contact me using admin email should they wish to get in touch.

Thus, my admin email does not receive anything but instead the email used to submit the form receives an email from the admin address

I was wondering if anyone could point me to a library or method for receiving user emails using python or flask?

The Flask mail documentation site isn't responding / seems to be down at the moment.

Thanks, 
Kyle

Comment: 1. Asking for libraries and other off-site resources is off-topic for SO 2. Web applications shouldn't really receive mails, that's why you have dedicated mail servers (unless you are planning on building your own mailing service)

Comment: Oops sorry, I hadn't realised that, I'll close this question down. Thanks for pointing it out and for your second point too, I'll do some more reading on what I'm doing. Thanks for you help